# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dask_geopandas'

Tags: pip, conda, dask, geopandas

i have dask, dask-core and dask geopandas installed as shown:

```
dask                      2021.7.1           pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
dask-core                 2021.7.1           pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
dask-geopandas            0.1.0a4                  pypi_0    pypi
```

however, when importing I kept getting an error message :

```
"ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dask_geopandas'"
```

I wonder what has gone wrong with installation, thank you.

Comment: How did you install? What did you try to import, exactly? Is there more information in the traceback?  Note that dask-geopandas is also on conda-forge, so that might be a better option.

Comment: Please add the output of `import sys; print(sys.executable); print(sys.path)` from the Python interpreter.  Does the former correspond to the environment you have `dask-geopandas` installed in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could happen if `pip install`  and `conda install` installed packages in different paths (this typically happens when the conda environment does not have its own `pip`).

A simple way out of this is to install everything with conda, so in this case you would run the following within your conda environment:

```sh
conda install -c conda-forge dask  dask-geopandas
```

Alternatively, make sure that your conda environment has `pip` installed also and then run the pip within the conda environment:

```sh
conda install -c conda-forge dask pip

# if the conda environment is not activate, then activate it
# using: conda activate the_name_of_your_env

pip install dask-geopandas
```

In addition, there are specific instructions at https://geopandas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started/install.html#installing-with-pip about extra steps you may need to take when using pip - you might need a compiler available in your system.

Comment: i got this error msg: "ImportError: cannot import name '_nonempty_index' from 'dask.dataframe.utils'"

Comment: this answer was considered but was not the final solution, considering that maybe some packages went broken during intalling/uninstalling. In the end, I created a new environment and then the installation went well.